# Xamarin.iOS iOS-Charts: Bar Chart not showing bars

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, ios-charts

I'm using iOSCharts in project to draw bar chart. There's no official documentations available for iOSCharts and on the github page it says all the api's are same as MPAndroidChart plot. I followed everything I used to do in the android, but bars of the bar chart are not showing. The entire chart takes up the color of the bars

This is how it's showing..

[image]

```
BarChartView barChart = new BarChartView();
ChartXAxis xAxis = barChart.XAxis;

xAxis.LabelPosition = XAxisLabelPosition.Bottom;
xAxis.DrawGridLinesEnabled = false;

xAxis.AxisLineColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#DEDEDE");
barChart.RightAxis.Enabled = false;
barChart.LeftAxis.DrawAxisLineEnabled = false;
barChart.LeftAxis.GridColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#DEDEDE");
barChart.LeftAxis.StartAtZeroEnabled = false;
barChart.Legend.Enabled = false;
barChart.LeftAxis.LabelCount = 5;

barChart.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#FFFFFF");
barChart.GridBackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("FFFFFF");
barChart.SetDescriptionText("");
barChart.MoveViewToX(7);

VitalGraph vGraph = ..............

barChart.SetData(GetBarData(vGraph.vitalId, vGraph));
barChart.Frame = measurementsChartContainer.Frame;
measurementsChartContainer.AddSubview(barChart);    



private BarChartData GetBarData(int vitalId, VitalGraph vGraph)
{
    List<float> valueList = vGraph.valueList.Select(x => float.Parse(x)).ToList();

    UIColor[] colorList = new UIColor[vGraph.colorList.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < vGraph.colorList.Count; i++)
        colorList[i] = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString(vGraph.colorList[i]);

    BarChartDataEntry[] entries = new BarChartDataEntry[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < valueList.Count; i++)
    {
        entries[i] = new BarChartDataEntry(valueList[i], i);
    }

    //barChart.MoveViewToX(valueList.Count)
    BarChartDataSet barDataSet = new BarChartDataSet(entries, "Vital Reading");
    barDataSet.BarSpace = 40f;

    NSString[] dayList = new NSString[vGraph.dayList.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < vGraph.dayList.Count; i++)
        dayList[i] = new NSString(vGraph.dayList[i]);

    List<IBarChartDataSet> dataList = new List<IBarChartDataSet>();
    dataList.Add(barDataSet);

    BarChartData barData = new BarChartData(dayList, dataList.ToArray());
    //barDataSet.SetColors(colorList);
    return barData; 
}
```

I had no trouble using MPAndroidChart in Xamarin.Drioid. Am I something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
BarChartDataSet yDataSet = new BarChartDataSet (barEntry, barChartModel.dataSetLegend [i]);
                    yDataSet.SetColor(UIColor.Red);
```

Hope it helps you.